# Select and JOIN count from two similar queries/tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have two or more tables and want to query the count of each together. These two tables have the same structure.

Here is my query to get the count of each:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM pt_test_orders 
WHERE payment_log = '100 - Success' AND DATE(created_at) = CURDATE()

SELECT count(*) FROM bs_test_orders 
WHERE payment_log = '100 - Success' AND DATE(created_at) = CURDATE()
```

if possible, I'm looking to get a result like this:

```
| table_name          | count |
-------------------------------
|     pt_test_orders  |     3 |
|     bs_test_orders  |     8 |
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: `SELECT 'pt_test_orders' table_name, 3 count UNION SELECT  'bs_test_orders', 8;` will work fine for that. For anything else, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION`

```
SELECT 'pt_test_orders' as TableName, count(*) FROM pt_test_orders 
WHERE payment_log = '100 - Success' AND DATE(created_at) = CURDATE()
UNION  
SELECT 'bs_test_orders'  as TableName, count(*) FROM bs_test_orders 
WHERE payment_log = '100 - Success' AND DATE(created_at) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: You are welcome!. You can accept it as the answer by clicking on the check.